# Is Continuous Integration feasible for iOS development?

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

Is Continuous Integration feasible for iOS.
Again my Jenkins build fails with ***“Your session has expired. Please log in.”*** and I begin to ask myself if Continuous Integration is at all feasible for iOS development.

How can you set up a reliable unattended build system that demands a user logged into some web service which might expire your login at any moment? As far as I see it the answer is: **You can't.**

It's just not possible. It will always be an unreliable system which will stop building for no apparent reason.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: I already saw it a couple of times, I think it was very well integrated with Azure DevOps which was a big surprise for me. In general Azure DevOps using integration with Fastlane. Do you use Fastlane in your Jenkins job??

Comment: @m1sh0 No —  cloud services are a no go.
—
We have a bog standard on premise native build and even that doesn't work.

Comment: Okay then in your Jenkins you can create a job with this https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/appstore-deployment/ and it will be fine. There is some stuff like how to increase build version and app version which can be a little bit tricky but in general, there is no problem to have everything fully automated.

Comment: @m1sh0 I'll look into it. Already got fastlane for Android installed so maybe it's indeed the way to go. We'll see.

Comment: I saw it in different configurations to work, but for sure it was not so easy to be done. At least for me, it took me a couple of days to make everything to work okay. But at the end of the day, it did the job.

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to the discussion in the comments, it is feasible. There is no simple way to explain everything that you need but in a short summary.

If you using Jenkins,

1. You need access to MacOS, Jenkins running on MacOs or Jenkins Slave which is with MacOS.
2. Xcode on the machine from point 1. with xcode(xcode comand tool) xcbuild.
3. Fastlane integrations (check [here](https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/appstore-deployment/))
4. The last thing is fine-tuning with your process, haw and when to increase builds and etc.

At some providers like Azure DevOps, it was easy to add all these BIG steps with build in components of the system.

In general, I never found a good tutorial about this how to be done end to end. But with a lot of reading and trying it was done from me, without to have big experience in the dev-ops world.

P.S. It will be nice if you do a good tutorial for how this can be done when you made it(I didn't have time to do it :( ).

Comment: I tried without fastlane. Just with the Jenkins xcode build step. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Yep same for me.